# Configuring Apache on top of GF3 - Not working

Tags: apache, primefaces, glassfish-3

I'm trying to configure Apache on top of Glassfish v3 using apj13.
But when I'm trying to access `http://<server_name>/myApp` but this is not working. It is keep on loading the page.

From Glassfish side I've not made any changes.

From Apache side I've edited the httpd.conf file to include virtual server using 
`JkMount /myApp/* worker1`

There was no helpful logs in either from Glassfish or Apache.

**Update**:
Worker.properties file

`worker.worker1.port=28081
worker.worker1.host=myservername 
worker.worker1.type=ajp13`

The application is using `Primefaces` if that helps.

Any help is much appreciated.!
Thanks.

Comment: There's not enough information here. Did you enable `mod_jk`? What is your worker definition? Does it work with with `proxy_ajp`?

Comment: Yes, `mod_jk` is enabled. I've updated my question.

Comment: I guess you already fixed this issue on your own. Maybe you can add an answer to explain how you fixed it (if so).

Comment: Ok. I'll add my solution to the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution for this.
I was having wrong configuration (incorrect port) in my `worker.properties` file. Below is the correct one (for me)

```
worker.worker1.port=8009 //the port was wrong. Instead of having APJ port I had HTTP port
worker.worker1.host=myservername 
worker.worker1.type=ajp13
```

Also I had included `socket_connect_timeout` to the properties file to check for any errors while communicating with JK and remote host.

Please note that I also had cluster enabled in my GF and I had to manually configured different `APJ_LISTENER_PORT` value in custer configuration page in Admin Console of GF.

Hope this might help someone.!